# .bar installer for PlayBook OS using WiFi?

Tags: blackberry, wifi, transfer, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

I'm trying to install some non-store .bar files to my trusty old BlackBerry PlayBook.

The problem: **the micro USB port is broken**. I charge the PlayBook using a dock, but can't install any .bar using the normal way.

Is there any way to install them using the WiFi data transfer thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. Simply enable WiFi and all developer tools accept IP address as the device parameter. Last parameter is path to the .bar file itself.

`blackberry-deploy.bat -installApp <device_name_or_ip> <bar_package_path>`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this Chrome extension named `BB10 / PlayBook App Manager` that does the job very well, via WiFi.

You can get it from Chrome extensions web store if you search for `playbook app manager`.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bb10-playbook-app-manager/kmbaalodpmjjhpobkgljnelbpblnikkp?hl=en